# jquery: Adding up numbers to the current value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add up numbers to the current value. what I am trying to do is almost a simple shopping cart using jQuery.

However, the issue that I am facing is that the numbers wont add up at all. but instead the numbers get replaced by the new one!

And in fact, I get some strange behavior!

To explain this better I've created this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x28z1rjj/1/)

My code is:

```
$('.addons').click(function() {
   var price2 = +$(this).attr('data-price'); 
   $('#fuelcellprice').val(price2); 
   var inputval = +$('#fuelcellprice').val();
   var finaltotal = price2 + inputval;

   alert(finaltotal);
});
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: it shouldn't be `= +` it must be `+=`

Comment: @AminJafari `var inputval = +$('#fuelcellprice').val();` is FINE. It's assigning the coerced string value to `inputval`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, I'm not sure why you voted to close this question even though you explained why but that sentence has no substance. STO is designed for developers to help eachother and that is whats expected from this site. so you're contribution is much appreciated if you answer the question instead of finding faults on the questions and voting them for them to be closed! thanks and have a good weekend.

Answer (score 1):

If `#fuelcellprice` stores your sum, set it at the very end of your handler. Don't use `+`, which is misleading for the purpose. I recommend you to rename your variables to reflect your intent accordingly:

```
$('.addons').click(function() {

   var itemPrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
   var currentSum = $('#fuelcellprice').val();
   var sum = itemPrice + currentSum;

   $('#fuelcellprice').val(sum); //store your final value here

   alert(sum);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

1st you need to use `parseFloat()`

2nd I don't know why you use `$('#fuelcellprice').val()` while you set it to price2

try this

```
var inputval = 0;
$('.addons').click(function() {
   var price2 = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));

   $('#fuelcellprice').val(price2);

   inputval += price2;

   alert(inputval);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/x28z1rjj/4/)

Comment: `parseFloat()` does not take a second argument for the radix, it's base 10 only. But I think it's planned for one of the next ECMA versions.